# segmentation fault in recursion

Tags: c, pointers

i am trying to learn tree with C. i need to find longest path. i am using recursive approach for this. but i am getting segmentation fault. i am not able to find why it is happening. i dont need logic. i want to do it on my own. just want to know what basic fault I am doing.

Any suggestion for handling pointers is most welcome.

```
void longestPath(struct node *p,int *maxlen,int count)
{
    if(p==NULL)
        return;

    count++;

    if(p->lft==NULL && p->rt==NULL )
    {
        if(*maxlen<count)
             *maxlen=count;
    }

    longestPath(p->lft,maxlen,count);
    longestPath(p->rt,maxlen,count); 
}
```

Comment: You want `||` instead of `&&`.

Comment: Shouldn't `p->lft==NULL && p->rt==NULL` be `p->lft==NULL || p->rt==NULL`?

Comment: Run in a debugger. It might be that you don't set the leaf nodes left or right pointers to `NULL`.

Comment: Looks like your tree itself is broken.

Comment: I agree with @self. I can't see any wrong thing in your function. Provided that it is called with a valid tree and valid pointer for maxlen, this should work. I also think that it's not || but && as you have put it, because you want to detect when you have come to the end of a branch.

Answer (score 2):

Check maxlen for NULL also.  That is likely the problem you are dereferecing the pointer without validating it.

```
int maxpath = 0;
int count = 10; // for example
struct node* nodes; // initialized somewhere else
longestPath( nodes, &maxpath, count );
```

Comment: thanks TimDave. it was same you said. was not using malloc. sometimes it works without malloc also. do you have any idea why. should i be always passing pointer only after malloc?

Comment: You can declare the variable on the stack and pass its address instead of using malloc.  See edited post for example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the result via a pointer, you could use the return value:

```
unsigned longestPath(struct node *p)
{
    unsigned ll,rr;

    if (!p) return 0;

    ll = longestPath(p->lft);
    rr = longestPath(p->rt);

    return ll > rr ? 1+ll : 1+rr;
}
```